# How to add a wordbank region to pygame

Tags: python, user-interface, object, pygame, python-3.6

I am required to add a wordbank for this client at my internship (for one who does not have any programming background whatsoever) to this pygame. The pygame shown below is a skeleton of what I have (obviously cannot show internal code to the internet) and I need a function where it takes the 2 text objects and places them in a separate region in vertical fashion like a wordbank on a history test or something.

**How do I implement this GUI-type element into this code using the pygame library?**

*Essentially* This game below runs to populate two textbox objects to be dragged around the screen y the user. I would like a designated (either external or internal) region to place these words in so that when the game loads the words are ordered down in a column to the side of the window.

```
import sys
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
FONT = pg.font.Font(None, 42)


class Text(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, text, pos, color, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.image = FONT.render(text, True, color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group(
        Text('hello', (100, 300), pg.Color('steelblue1')),
        Text('world', (250, 300), pg.Color('sienna1')),
        )

    selected = None
    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                for sprite in all_sprites:
                    if sprite.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        selected = sprite
                        break
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                selected = None
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION:
                if selected:
                    selected.rect.center = event.pos

        all_sprites.update()
        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        all_sprites.draw(screen)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Your "I need a function where it takes the 2 text objects and places them in a separate region in vertical fashion" is too vague. Please [edit] your question and explain in more detail and how that relates to what the code in your question currently does.

Comment: Did the edit help?

Comment: Yes, that's better. `pygame` itself doesn't do multiple windows. It's possible to use multiprocessing and create a subtask that also used it and ran its own main display loop, but then it and the main process would need to communicate using [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), which can get complicated. Within a single `pygame` program, you could make the column of words a group of sprites which would allow you to do some operations, such as moving them, collectively. What exactly will the user / program interaction with them go or be?

Comment: The interaction involves the user placing the word objects in 4 subcategories divided in 4 quadrants. Imagine the window being divided into 4 squares equally. I wanted the words to have some sort of GUI-like function where when they run the game it loads in a list of words to the side, however you said a separate window does not work so hm...

Comment: It might be just simpler to edit the background image to have a wider resolution and just populate the words in that region. I guess the next question is how do I blit all the words in a column list on the screen?

Comment: Is the user is just going to be viewing this vertical list of words or want to do more, like being able to select one of them or select and drag one of them somewhere (possibly removing it from the vertical list)?

Comment: Yes the user is going to see this list of words in a column, and then drag and drop the words in each of the 4 regions removing each one from the column.

Comment: That's actually a lot of functionality. I'll see if I can put together something with at least some of it implemented.

Comment: Just an idea of how the text boxes are generated is enough.

Comment: You're already doing that with the `FONT.render(text, True, color)` call (which returns a new `Surface` with the specified text rendered on it). `pygame` doesn't really have what could be called a "text box" class—you'll need to write your own (which is what I was thinking of implementing).

Comment: ahhh I see, okay

Comment: The code looks familiar. ;) If I understand you correctly, you just need a few areas that recognize if a text object is placed inside of them, so you could use `pygame.Rect`s and their colliderect method and append the text objects to a list or other data structure if they collide with the area. Then iterate over this list and blit the text objects with some offset.

Comment: Very good suggestion. Because I do not feel like redoing my custom background image.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that demonstrates what I mentioned in the comment. I just use the `area` rect to define a region where you can drop the text objects and append them to the `text_objects` list. If I select one of these objects I just remove them from the list.

```
import sys
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
FONT = pg.font.Font(None, 42)


class Text(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, text, pos, color, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.image = FONT.render(text, True, color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group(
        Text('hello', (300, 300), pg.Color('steelblue1')),
        Text('world', (450, 300), pg.Color('sienna1')),
        )

    area = pg.Rect(100, 70, 100, 300)
    text_objects = []
    selected = None
    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                for sprite in all_sprites:
                    if sprite.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        selected = sprite
                        if selected in text_objects:
                            text_objects.remove(selected)
                        break
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                if selected and selected.rect.colliderect(area):
                    selected.rect.centerx = area.centerx
                    text_objects.append(selected)
                selected = None
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION:
                if selected:
                    selected.rect.center = event.pos

        all_sprites.update()

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        pg.draw.rect(screen, (190, 120, 20), area, 2)
        for y, sprite in enumerate(text_objects):
            sprite.rect.y = y * sprite.rect.h + area.top
        all_sprites.draw(screen)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()
```